# Accidentally merged master into develop and pushed

Tags: git, github

I work in a git repo where we maintain a master and a develop branch. Changes are made in develop and merged into master before releases. Today I accidentally merged master into develop and pushed the result to develop. A `git log` in develop now shows the `merge develop into master` commits. I need to fix this somehow. I found the most recent good commit using `git reflog`. What is the correct approach to revert to it?

Since I have already pushed, I would like to avoid rewriting history. However, I'm not sure that I can use `git revert`. I'm not convinced that the "revert a faulty merge" howto and other SO questions apply since the commits that I want to revert are merges themselves (https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You *can* use `git revert` to revert the merge.  Just be aware that when you do that, you make a future "re-merge" more difficult.  Read that message you linked closely—it says a lot about how to make the future "re-merge" work—but be aware that it's talking about merging `develop` into `master`, and you said you did the opposite, merged `master` into `develop`:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E          <-- master
      \          \
       F - G - H - M           <-- develop
```

In this case (having merged `master` into `develop` instead of the other way around) you can choose a number of different options, all with advantages and drawbacks...

#### The easiest method, which I prefer if it's an option

(0) Do nothing.  If merging in `C` and `D` doesn't break the `develop` branch, just leave it that way.  Later, someone will `git checkout master` and `git merge --no-ff develop` and get this (let's say one more commit `I` got added to `develop` first):

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- M2    <-- master
      \          \      /
       F - G - H - M - I       <-- develop
```

Here `merge` finds what's been done in `develop` since it split off from `master`, which was at `B`.  So it puts in `F`, `G`, and `H`, skips any parts of `M` that came off `master` (probably all of it), and finally puts in `I` and makes merge-commit `M2` (because of commit `E`; but if `E` were not there, it would be because I used `--no-ff` too).

#### Some easy methods with obvious drawbacks

(1) Just "rewrite history": erase commit `M` from branch `develop`.  Alert everyone else who uses the branch that this is about to happen: that commit `M` is going away and they should take whatever measures they must, to handle this.

(2) Stop using the old name `develop`, make a new branch name `develop1` or whatever:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E          <-- master
     |           \
     |             M           <-- develop
      \          /
       F - G - H               <-- develop1
```

This is the same as option (1) except that the commit `M` is still there, along with the branch label on it, and you have a new/different branch label pointing to commit `H`.  You still need to alert everyone, but it might make their jobs easier.  You can delete `develop` later, when everyone is good with that.

#### The revert and its drawbacks

(3) Revert the merge.  As in the linked article, let's use `W` to represent the new revert commit:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E          <-- master
      \          \
       F - G - H - M - W       <-- develop
```

What's in `W`?  Whatever it takes to "erase the effect" of the merge.  In this case, that means, changes that un-do whatever was done in `C` and `D`.  So far so good, `develop` has just the changes from `F`, `G`, and `H`, again.  The problem occurs *later*, if/when someone does:

```
git checkout master
git merge develop
```

The second command goes rooting around to find where `master` and `develop` were split, i.e., commit `B`, so it picks up all the changes since then.  Which at this point include those in `W`, which will *un*-do `C` and `D`, not at all what you wanted.  It can be fixed-up afterward, but whoever does the merge has to know about this "delete `C` and `D`" time-bomb waiting for them.

Note that this is the same merge as in the "do nothing" option (0).  The issue here is the *contents* of `W`.  In case (0), you *want* the contents of commit `I`, but here you *don't* want the contents of `W`.

#### One more option

This is arguably the worst option of all, given what's shown above, but I'll list it anyway:

(4) make an all-new branch with *copies* of the commits you want to keep, and name it `develop`.  (Or name it something else, but then we're back to the `develop1`-like situation above, and you should probably just use that one.)  Whether you keep the `old-develop` branch, or just abandon it (by not labeling it), is up to you, but I will draw it in:

```
       F' - G' - H'            <-- develop
      /
A -- B -- C -- D -- E          <-- master
      \          \
       F - G - H - M           <-- old-develop
```

This is described in the link you included.  It's only really useful in more complex cases.

Comment: +1 just for the time you must had spend for these drawings ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by resetting your local branch back to the last good commit, then pushing that:

```
git checkout develop
git reset --hard lastgoodcommit
git push origin develop
```

Note that your upstream repository may disallow non-fast-forward merges by default. If so, you will need to modify that option on your upstream, do the above push, and then restore the original setting.

Comment: The standard way to do that would be `push --force`, and OP said they didn't want to rewrite history if possible.

Comment: Well sure, but not "not wanting to rewrite history", and "revert a faulty merge" are largely incompatible goals. The problem is that if you do anything other than rewriting history, then it will appear that previous commits on `master` have already been merged into `develop` even though they haven't (after doing whatever you did to try to undo this).

Comment: Do you mean because they'll still show up in the `git log`? And that the history will only be clear if you see the revert as well?

Comment: Yes, those commits from master will still show up in the log, and some tools will think those commits are already present in your develop branch, even though a later revert has undone their effect. If you can handle it, it's definitely best to force a push to rewind history.

Answer (score 0):

I use GIT Extensions. There is a feature to right click a revision in the UI and revert back to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can revert a merge, but you need to specify which parent is the mainline. Since you merged develop into master, this should do the trick:

```
git revert --mainline 1 HEAD
```

To make sure you have exactly what you want, you should do a diff with $lastgoodcommit, however, $lastgoodcommit should be HEAD^. This is of course, if you haven't made commits on top of the merge, if you have, then you need to replace HEAD with the merge commit.

Finally, you can also do the revert manually, by checking out the code on top of the current commit:

```
git checkout $lastgoodcommit -- .
```

The '-- .' is there to differentiate from a normal checkout, where HEAD is switched to the specified commit, in the command here, all the files in the working directory, and the staging area, are going to be exactly the same as they were in $lastgoodcommit. If you do a diff with $lastgoodcommit, you should see, again, no changes. Essentially it's a revert.

You could also try '`git checkout --patch`' to selectively revert chunks of code.